# String mismatch error regarding packageManager and getLaunchIntentForPackage in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, intellij-idea, type-mismatch

I am creating an android launcher app using Kotlin, and I am running the following code to activate an app. I have an app drawer that displays my user apps, and when I click on one of them, I want it to activate the app with this code:

```
override fun getView(position:Int, convertView:View, parent:ViewGroup):View 
{
    val v:View
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_app, parent, false)
    }
    else
    {
        v = convertView
    }

    val myLayoutView = v.findViewById(R.id.layout) as LinearLayout
    val myImageView = v.findViewById(R.id.image) as ImageView
    val myLabelView =v.findViewById(R.id.label) as TextView

    val app = getItem(position) as AppObject
    myLabelView.text = app.appName
    myImageView.setImageDrawable(app.appImage)

    myLayoutView.setOnClickListener(object: View.OnClickListener 
    {
        override fun onClick(v:View)
        {
            val launchAppIntent = context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.appPackageName)
            if (launchAppIntent != null)
            {
                context.startActivity(launchAppIntent)
            }
        }
    })
    return v
}
```

The error I get is in the line:

```
 val launchAppIntent = context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.appPackageName)
```

*appPackageName* is of type *String?* but *getLaunchIntentForPackage()* requires *String*. I've tried tacking *toString()* on the end of *app.appPackageName* but that does not work.

I think the problem I'm having lies in my ignorance of Kotlin's null avoidance fussiness and I just don't really know how to get around it yet since I'm brand new to Kotlin and app development at that.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You could check appPackageName before invoking this method and make sure it isn't null. For example, ```if (app.appPackageName != null) ...```

Comment: Hi thank you @tomerpacific ! I tried putting it before myLayout.setOnClickListener, before override fun onClick, and before val launcherAppIntent, but it's still having issues. Where do you recommend I place the check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are receiving is because when you access `app.appPackageName` there is a chance that the application's package name may be null. This is because this method is originally written in Java and Kotlin protects itself in case of the value null. That is why it's type is String?.

To overcome this issue, you need to add a nullability check before accessing this value. That way, Kotlin will interpret it's type as String.

```
override fun getView(position:Int, convertView:View, parent:ViewGroup):View 
{
    val v:View
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_app, parent, false)
    }
    else
    {
        v = convertView
    }

    val myLayoutView = v.findViewById(R.id.layout) as LinearLayout
    val myImageView = v.findViewById(R.id.image) as ImageView
    val myLabelView =v.findViewById(R.id.label) as TextView

    val app = getItem(position) as AppObject
    myLabelView.text = app.appName
    myImageView.setImageDrawable(app.appImage)

    myLayoutView.setOnClickListener(object: View.OnClickListener 
    {
        override fun onClick(v:View)
        {
            val applicationPackageName : String? = app.appPackageName
            if (applicationPackageName != null) {

                  val launchAppIntent = context.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(applicationPackageName)
                  if (launchAppIntent != null)
                  {
                    context.startActivity(launchAppIntent)
                  }
                }
           } else {
             //YOUR LOGIC
           }
    })
    return v
}
```

Comment: Thanks again @tomerpacific , but I still get the following Run error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter convertView`

Comment: The error message you are referencing relates to a different parameter, convertView. This does not have anything to do with your original question. If this is a different issue, you can open another question.

Comment: you're right, not sure why I didn't notice it. I fixed the error but I still am not able to activate the apps when I click on them so I will open another question. Thanks again for all your help!